# AngularJS service returning response to wrong controller instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, controller

*[NOTE: Since I'm not quite sure where to start looking for the issue, I'm not including any sample code for now. Depending on the comments/suggestions, I will edit this post and add whatever is needed]*

We are working on a SPA web application (AngularJS) and recently observed a strange behavior (apparently, it is there from the very beginning but only now it was detected). The application is designed to work in a multi-tabs approach, each tab specializing on a specific type of data and contains a "Refresh" button to re-load data from the DB. For instance, there is a tab that serves to create and update User Profiles and a second tab to create and update Users. Each tab is assigned its own (differently named) controller.

When opening two different tabs, say one for Profiles and the other for Users, each tab receives its own data and there is a clear distinction between the different scopes.

The problem starts when two tabs of the same type are open (say, two instances of the User Profiles tab):

- A query to the DB triggered from within the first opened (instance) tab is received within the second instance.
- A query to the DB triggered from within the second opened (instance) tab is ALSO received within the second instance.
- When the second instance is closed, any additional queries from the first tab get no response.

I would appear that the second instance somehow overrides the pointer to the promise function (that is invoked as soon as the response from the DB arrives). One simple test we did to confirm this hypothesis was to use the unique ID of each tab. A console print was added to the code just before triggering the DB retrieval and when the response is received. The result was that triggering a request from `Tab_ID = 0` was received within `Tab_ID = 1`.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a code example that reproduces the issue.  It might be that you are using a common service. When you open a new tab you create a new "DB" listener. When you close a tab, you close all of the listeners of this type.
Again - it's hard to tell. If you could share some code or better - a working example on plnkr/codepen/fiddle it would allow for more specific insights.

Comment: Thank you @yccteam for your comment. Please refer to the EDIT that describes a very simple solution. Cheers!!!!

Comment: @FDavidov sorry, but your question makes no sense to other users as it is completely unclear. And passing $scope anywhere is 99% bad solution.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, I'm not passing `$scope` but simply defining the promise (function) as a `$scope` object. That way, two instances of the same controller have different instantiations of the promise functions (because each controller has its own `$scope`). I see nothing wrong with this. Do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

I just found a solution, actually a beautifully simple one: make the promise function part of the controller's `$scope`. That's it!

Just to make clearer the solution, the initial promise function looked like the following:

```
 Handle_Server_Response = function (data) {...}
```

and the callback pointer was passed as follows:

```
Get_Data_From_Sarver(<arguments>...,Handle_Server_Response) ;
```

The new code looks now as follows:

```
 $scope.Handle_Server_Response = function (data) {...}
```

and the callback pointer is now passed as follows:

```
Get_Data_From_Sarver(<arguments>...,$scope.Handle_Server_Response) ;
```

This very simple modification makes sure that callback functions are within the correct **scope** of the controller's instance.